# Java - Ошибка при компиляции HelloWorld.java через терминал

Tags: java, кодировка, terminal, компиляция

Недавно начал изучать Java, столкнулся с проблемой при компиляции кода через терминал (Mac OS X).
Программа:

```
public class HelloWorld {
    public static void main(String args []) {
        System.out.println(«Hello World!»)
    }
}
```

Перешел в терминале в директорию с файлом `cd desktop` запустил компиляцию `javac HelloWorld.java`, появилось сообщение о 61 ошибке:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
В чем моя ошибка и как это исправить?

Через NetBeans все работает, но, насколько я понимаю, самый первый метод, без использования дополнительного софта именно через терминал, хочется освоить и его.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Скорее всего у вас кодировка не utf-8, однако и в исходнике есть проблемы, вопервых в конце строки

> ```
> System.out.println(«Hello World!»)
> ```

не хватает точки с запятой `;` 
и кавычки в которые заключена строка тоже выглядят странно: `«»`, должны быть вот такие: `"`

Comment: Спасибо большое, сейчас исправлю и перепроверю.

Comment: Большое спасибо! Видимо дело было в кодировке - использовал Xcode и исправил ошибки - все сработало.